# Jquery Datepicker throws Error on setDate

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm having and issue where when i try to use the setDate method of the jquery datepicker I get the following error:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

The code is as follows, and the error happens in the last line of the code.
I can try setDate with multiple different dates, using date objects, no matter what I do, i get the error.

```
$('.revEndDateInput').datepicker({
        format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
        startView: "days", 
        minViewMode: "days",
        language: 'pt-BR',
        orientation: 'bottom right',
});

$(".revEndDateInput").datepicker().on('changeDate', function(){
    var ThisID = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1];

    var StartDate = $('#revStartDateInput-'+ThisID).datepicker('getDate');
    var EndDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
    if (EndDate <= StartDate) {
        var ChosenDate = $.format.date(StartDate, 'dd/MM/yyyy');
        var HiddenDate = $.format.date(StartDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    }

    else{
        var ChosenDate = $.format.date(EndDate, 'dd/MM/yyyy');
        var HiddenDate = $.format.date(EndDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');  
    }


    $('#revEndDateInput-'+ThisID).attr('value',ChosenDate);
    $('#revEndDate-'+ThisID).attr('value',HiddenDate);

    $(this).datepicker('hide');

    $(this).datepicker( "setDate", "10/12/2012" );
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: can you post your html  too?

Comment: Google for `recursion` - (So ya, on `"setDate"` (or `.attr('value',ChosenDate);` ?) it triggers again the `changeDate` and so on and so on and so on till it hits hard and notifies you about the problem.) - It can be easily debugged using Chrome's developer tools, **set a breakpoint** inside your `function`, click *next step* until you identify which of those lines calls/triggers recursively (infinitely) the same function all over again.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, I totally missed that point, thanks man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this minor change it doesn't loop more than a second time after the date is fixed:

```
//End date picker
$('.revEndDateInput').datepicker({
        format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
        startView: "days", 
        minViewMode: "days",
        language: 'pt-BR',
        orientation: 'bottom right',
        autoclose: 'true'

});

$(".revEndDateInput").datepicker().on('hide', function(){
    var ThisID = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1];
    var StartDate = $('#revStartDateInput-'+ThisID).datepicker('getDate');
    var EndDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
    console.log('asd');
    if (EndDate < StartDate) {
        $(this).datepicker( "setDate", StartDate);
        var ChosenDate = $.format.date(StartDate, 'dd/MM/yyyy');
        var HiddenDate = $.format.date(StartDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    }

    else{
        var ChosenDate = $.format.date(EndDate, 'dd/MM/yyyy');
        var HiddenDate = $.format.date(EndDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');  
    }


    $('#revEndDateInput-'+ThisID).attr('value',ChosenDate);
    $('#revEndDate-'+ThisID).attr('value',HiddenDate);

    $(this).datepicker('hide');


}); //changeDate
```

Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

what @Roko said,, you are hitting the loop,,  put your code in onSelect function,, like this

```
$('.revEndDateInput').datepicker({
        format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
        startView: "days", 
        minViewMode: "days",
        language: 'pt-BR',
        orientation: 'bottom right',
        onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
            var ThisID = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1];

            var StartDate = $('#revStartDateInput-'+ThisID).datepicker('getDate');
            var EndDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            if (EndDate <= StartDate) {
                var ChosenDate = $.format.date(StartDate, 'dd/MM/yyyy');
                var HiddenDate = $.format.date(StartDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
            }

            else{
                var ChosenDate = $.format.date(EndDate, 'dd/MM/yyyy');
                var HiddenDate = $.format.date(EndDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');  
            }


            $('#revEndDateInput-'+ThisID).attr('value',ChosenDate);
            $('#revEndDate-'+ThisID).attr('value',HiddenDate);

            $(this).datepicker('hide');

            $(this).datepicker( "setDate", "10/12/2012" )
        }
});
```

see if that fix it

P.S. I have only pasted your code in `onSelect` callback, you have to match it to your needs

Comment: This doesn't really work, but with the clarification @Roko made I guess i can find a way now :)